# What do peak-to-valley and mm/µV mean?

Tags: terminology, units

I was reading a document where it says

> Adjust the signal generator to apply a 1mV peak-to-valley input 6Hz
>   triangular signal at a gain of 0.001mm/µV.

What does peak-to-valley mean hear? Is it same as peak to peak?
And, what does mm/µV mean?

Comment: Show the document please.

Comment: Sounds like a strain gauge calibrator to me.

Comment: @user36129 - I was thinking EKG/EEG, or some other medical device. That sounds like the typical range of a lot of bioelectrical signals.

Comment: @ConnorWolf you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peak to valley means the highest point of the signal to the lowest point. It's a little like peak-peak except that it implies a DC bias so that the "negative peaks" don't cross 0V, so valley is a better name for them.

mm/µv means millimetres per microvolt, or metres per millivolt. What THAT means depends on context you haven't given us, but for example, mm may refer to the signal amplitude on the display of a REALLY SENSITIVE oscilloscope (or an oscilloscope driven from an amplifier).

Comment: If I apply 2V peak-to-peak sine wave and add 0.5V dc offset, so that the highest peak is 1.5V and lowest is -0.5V. The peak-to-peak is still 2V but peak-to-valley is 1.5V. If there is no dc offset, the peak-to-valley is 1V. Am I right?

Comment: No, because the lowest voltage is -0.5V not 0V or 0.5V. In that case, peak-valley is still 2V.

Comment: Then in which case, peak-peak is different than peak-valley?

Comment: There is no case where they are different. However, when there is no zero crossing, peak-valley is perhaps a less confusing name.